# Why does the decider get invoked multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

While trying to run the booking [sample](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/booking/BookingWorkflowImpl.java), the decider gets invoked 4 times (i.e. the makeBooking method), but only a single call gets sent to the activity task exposed by ActivityHost.java. Can someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity tasks suppose to be long/heavy operations. SWF sees that activity was executed in Workflow history and skip it.

Decider on the other hand suppose to be fast. SWF will run it multiple times, injecting results of Activities when they are available. This is called [Replay](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/concepts.html#concepts.replay) in flow framework.